# Matplotlib Imshow Doesn't Update With Draw

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble getting imshow to update with new data. For reference I'm pulling data off a serial port and trying to plot it, updating every second or so. I had been accumulating the data with a thread, so I initially thought that might be the problem as matplotlib isn't thread safe. However, I can't get the following simpler example to work:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    import time
    dat = np.random.rand(100,10)
    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    image = ax.imshow(np.zeros((10,10)))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    count = 0
    while count < 100:
        image.set_data(dat[count:count+10])
        fig.canvas.draw()
        count += 10
        time.sleep(1)
```

Using TkAgg, I just get the plot of all zeros, it never updates then quits.
With Qt5Agg, an empty window pops up before quitting.

I've tried various combinations of draw_idle(), flush_events() and plt.show(block=False), with the same results.

python 3.8.10 , matplotlib 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after posting this I figured out the solution.
I initialized the plot with all zeros - changing this to be a random array of values fixes it fixes it.

I'm not sure why starting with all zeros broke the color scaling, though from the matplotlib documentation the default normalization scales the input data on [0,1], so I suspect that was the issue.